# duplicate years and days in UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

there is a weird problem with `UIDatePicker` when I set its calendar to `NSIslamicCalendar` or `NSIslamicCivilCalendar` like this:

```
picker.calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSIslamicCalendar];
```

And try to choose a first day or a last day of a random year, I notice that the current selected year is duplicated and the 2nd day of the month appears before the 1st day, as you can see in the following screenshot :

[image]

where `Muharram` is the name of the first month and `Dhu'l-Hijjah` is  the name of the last month of the islamic calendar.

is this a bug in the `UIDatePicker` or should I do some workaround to get rid of this glitch ?

p.s. this is noticed in iOS 6 & 7 simulators and there is no other properties has been set for the picker except for its calendar property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, finally I realized that it is a **bug** in the picker and ended up with a custom picker, Apple dudes didn't bother themselves to create a perfect Islamic calendar, but they have put a little effort to customize the picker to fit the Hijri date, you can report this bug to Apple by the way.

I suggest not to count on it, you need to do a good work customizing it or you can start working on a custom picker for Hijri date.

Comment: is it ok to share your custom picker ?

Comment: @JAHelia I am so sorry I can't, it is not my app now, but it is a pretty easy: create a 3 fields picker with 3 arrays of corresponding day, month and year, if you faced any issue I am ready to help.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like that the islamic calender never have 31 days in month, so instead of date 31 the they have written 2.which is disabled all time,so i think you dont need to worry about it.it looks like bug to manage the calender with all other locality calenders.

Comment: islamic calendar has 30 days but that does not mean to show (2) before (1) and then show (2) again

Comment: @wasim Why is your answer an exact duplicate of the earlier answer (which is now deleted)?

Comment: @JAHelia thats right but thats what they have done. and its in every month if you check it well. rmaddy i was on other pc in offoce and didnt notice thay i have answered from other employees account